# Disable an Einstein bot with Apex

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, einstein-chatbot

I have dedicated a lot of time to eradicated manual steps from my deployments, and one that I'm stuck on is Einstein bots.

If you try to deploy a bot, it must be inactive otherwise, "Can't edit an active bot version" is returned.

I would like to add a simple Apex utility that disables the bot pre-deployment and re-enables it post deployment as part of my pipeline.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I was interested in doing this as well. Looks like BotVersion.Status has updateable = false, so I think this is fully impossible.